# Advanced Queries - Partial Match

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to figure out the best way to query very variable data in a Cloudant/CouchDB database. The only way for me to explain it is by showing an example:

**Database example**

```
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "query-able_values": {
            "value-type-b": "some value",
            "value-type-c": "some other value",
            "value-type-d": "another value",
            "value-type-f": "yet another value",
        }
    }

    {
        "_id": "2",
        "query-able_values": {
            "value-type-a": "value",
            "value-type-c": "some other value",
            "value-type-d": "another value"
        }
    }

    {
        "_id": "3",
        "query-able_values": {
            "value-type-a": "some value",
            "value-type-e": "some other one",
        }
    }
```

**Query Example**

Now suppose the user performs the following query:

```
    "selector": {
        "query-able_values.value-type-a": "value",
        "query-able_values.value-type-b": "a value not present in the database",
        "query-able_values.value-type-c": "some other value",
        "query-able_values.value-type-d": "another value",
        "query-able_values.value-type-e": "a value not present in the database",
        "query-able_values.value-type-f": "a value not present in the database"
    }
```

What do I need to change so that the query will hit database entry with id 2?

**EDIT**
I wasn't entirely clear in my original question. The user is completely agnostic of what is in the database and thus, of which values are relevant. The user simply has values **a** through **f**. I'm trying to figure out a way to get the "closest matching database entry".

Answer (score 1):

According to `CouchDB` [selector syntax](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#find-selectors), this could be written as follows.

```
"selector": {
    "query-able_values": {
        "value-type-a": "value",
        "value-type-b": { "$exists": false },
        "value-type-c": "some other value",
        "value-type-d": "another value",
        "value-type-e": { "$exists": false },
        "value-type-f": { "$exists": false }
    }
}
```

or with explicit equality operator.

```
"selector": {
    "query-able_values": {
        "value-type-a": { "$eq": "value"},
        "value-type-b": { "$exists": false },
        "value-type-c": { "$eq": "some other value"},
        "value-type-d": { "$eq": "another value"},
        "value-type-e": { "$exists": false },
        "value-type-f": { "$exists": false }
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice now that I forgot to mention that the user's query is completely agnostic. It doesn't "know" which values are irrelevant to what database entries. The user has values a through f. I'm trying to figure out a way to get the "closest matching database entry". I'll update my original question to clarify this. Thanks for your response!